# Вопрос публикации приложения в App Store

Tags: appstore, ios

**Дано:**

Приложение под iOS, реализующее интерфейс к онлайн сервису (возможно нескольким) посредством открытия мобильной версии сайта в окне приложения.

Функционально приложение реализует каталог определенных страниц нескольких веб-сайтов.
При выборе какого-то пункта, открывается мобильная версия конкретной страницы нужного сайта.

На этой странице будет выполняться веб-приложение (калькулятор, форма, игра и т.п.).

**Вопрос:**

Пропустят ли такое приложение в App Store при проверке?

*P.S. Я понимаю, что могут не пропустить по самым различным причинам. Но если по описанному выше уже ясно, что не пропустят, то хотелось бы узнать об этом до начала разработки.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по вашему описанию нарушений, вроде, нет. Там есть нюансы на счет GUI, иконок, и т.д.
Если сомневаетесь, то напишите им. Они ответят, там тоже люди работают :).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

это как рулетка, все зависит от цензора который будет проверять ваше приложение. Приложение должно отвечать требованиям apple которые они предъявляют. Пока не попробуете не узнаете.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.